# Is the entire blockchain (including the genesis block) stored forever?

Tags: storage, scalability

Quick question: Is the complete blockchain for Ethereum stored for as long as the currency exists? If not, then what determines the amount of time the binary for a contract can exist to be called? If yes, then would that present a scalability issue as the currency ages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes**, though there is ongoing discussion of ["Blockchain Rent"](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/35).

The argument why storage would not be a scalability issue, is that the rate of storage getting cheaper is higher than the rate of storage that the blockchain needs: thus everyone can comfortably afford and buy more storage, for all general purposes, and the space consumption of the blockchain would only be a fraction of that.  But there are still discussions of "rent", as linked above on the Ethereum EIPs repository, as it might improve the system further.

Answer (score 7):

Part of what defines a "block chain" is that new data is intrinsically based off older data. Cryptography allows us to to accomplish this by calculating a hash and embedding it in subsequent blocks of data. Changing a single value anywhere in the history would require altering all child data, invalidating everything.

However, this concept is different from the idea of rent-seeking for space on the blockchain. During development, it was considered to charge a contract for space consumed over time, however this was not included in the initial version of the main network. At present, all deployed contracts exist forever unless destroyed through the `SUICIDE` opcode ([also named `SELFDESTRUCT`](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-6.md)).

This is considered a [scalability issue](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Problems#1-blockchain-scalability), and several proposals have been made on how to handle [this particular problem](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/35), though no concrete implementations exist. Some additional techniques to deal with increasing blockchain size may be state-pruning or splitting the network into [discrete shards](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/53).